# Request interceptor object mutation

Tags: angularjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have a request interceptor which right now does two things, convert a moment object into a backend compatible string, and convert `true` or `false` into `1` or `0`.

Problem is that when for example a boolean is converted so is the object in the controller which it came from.

How can I "duplicate" the object, so the object in the request is different from the original?

I have tried `_.assign()`, `angular.copy()` and also convert it to and from `JSON`.

**Interceptor**

```
app.factory('requestInterceptor', function () {
function walk(obj) {
    _.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (moment.isMoment(obj[key])) {
            // Do conversion
        }

        if (obj[key] === false || obj[key] === true) {
            obj[key] = obj[key] ? 1 : 0;
        }

        if (_.isArray(obj[key]) || _.isObject(obj[key])) {
            walk(obj[key]);
        }
    });
}

return {
    request(request) {
        if (request.data) {
            // let data = JSON.stringify(request.data);
            // request.data = JSON.parse(data);
            walk(request.data);
        }

        return request;
    },
    requestError(request) {
        return request;
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should copy the object in your controller and use that copy in your request instead of original object.

```
$scope.data = angular.copy($scope.formData);
$http.post(url, $scope.data)
   .then(
       function(response){
           ....
       }, 
       function(response){
           ....
       }
    );
```